# Angular Routing- Not Found not always redirecting to Not Found

Tags: angular

I've added a NotFoundComponent to my angular app, but I'm noticing some strange behavior.  Here is my code in app-routing.module.ts:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'instructions', component: InstructionsComponent },
  { path: 'foo', component: FooComponent, canDeactivate: [DeactivateGuard] },
  { path: 'bar', component: BarComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/instructions', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

If I search for "myapp/foo", I get the FooComponent (which is correct).
If I search for "myapp/fooTest", I get the NotFoundComponent (which is correct).

If I search for "myapp/foo/test", I get a blank screen (which is incorrect).  And this is my question.  Why isn't it routing to the NotFoundComponent if I have a "/" in my incorrect search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer actually ended up being something weird.  This line was commented out in index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

When I brought that code back, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you haven't set up any `pathMatch` for your `foo` path. This way you have default `pathMatch: prefix` which means that any URL starting with `foo` will match this route.

`fooTest` is not considered to match this rule because it looks up for paths equal to `foo` or started with `foo/` (so it matches all children of `foo`)

If you want to redirect `/foo/test` to `NotFoundComponent`, then set `pathMatch: full` on `foo` path

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried pathMatch: 'full' and pathMatch: 'prefix" and neither worked.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What exactly happens if you add `pathMatch: 'full'` to `foo` and then try to access `/foo/test`? Which component is loaded?
Could you create stackblitz with code to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following path definition in your routes array.

This will match any segment past the "foo" prefix in your URL then redirect it to your NotFoundComponent component:

```
{    
    path: 'foo',
    children: [
        {
            path: ':anyother',
            component: NotFoundComponent
        }
    ],
},
```

The \foo route itself will route to the FooComponent.

The :anyother path segment will match any value.

So, the above will route as follows:

```
/foo will route to FooComponent.
/foo/test will route to NotFoundComponent.
```